# Realloc core dumped error in C

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to familiarize myself with calloc and realloc. I keep getting the below error when the code runs this line:

```
pb *newPhoneBook = (pb *) realloc(PhoneBook, (10 * sizeof(pb)));

realloc: malloc.c:2842: mremap_chunk: Assertion `((size + offset) & (_rtld_global_ro._dl_pagesize - 1)) == 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Program runs fine up until this particular line. Am I not using the realloc function correctly?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct phonebook {
   char cFirstName[30];
   char cLastName[30];
   char cNumber[30];
} pb;

int entry();
void convert_u(char *);

int main()
{
   int iResponse = 0;

   do {
      printf("\nPhonebook Menu\n****************\n\n");
      printf("1. Enter new contact\n2. Modify existing contact\n3. Exit\n\n");
      printf("Please make selection: ");
      scanf("%d", &iResponse);

      if (iResponse == 1) {
         entry();
      }
      else if (iResponse == 2) {
         //modify();
         printf("\nWorking on it...\n");
      }
   } while (iResponse != 3);

   return 0;
}

int entry()
{
   int x;
   char yes_no[] = "YES";
   pb Book = {'\0', '\0', '\0'};
   pb *PhoneBook = (pb *) calloc(5, sizeof(pb));
   PhoneBook = &Book;

   if (PhoneBook == NULL) {
      printf("\nMemory allocation failed.\n\n");
      return 1;
   }

   for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
      if (x > 0) {
         printf("\nAnother entry(yes/no)? ");
         scanf("%s", yes_no);
         convert_u(yes_no);
      }

      if (strcmp(yes_no, "YES") == 0 && x > 0) {
         pb *newPhoneBook = (pb *) realloc(PhoneBook, (10 * sizeof(pb))); //fails here
         if (newPhoneBook == NULL) {
            printf("\nOut of memory!\n\n");
            return 1;
         }
         else {
            PhoneBook = newPhoneBook;
         }
      }
      else if (strcmp(yes_no, "NO") == 0) {
         break;
      }

      printf("\nFirst Name: ");
      scanf("%s", PhoneBook[x].cFirstName);

      printf("\nLast Name: ");
      scanf("%s", PhoneBook[x].cLastName);

      printf("\nPhone Number: ");
      scanf("%s", PhoneBook[x].cNumber);

   }
}

void convert_u(char *yes_no)
{
   int x;

   for (x = 0; x < strlen(yes_no); x++) {
      yes_no[x] = toupper(yes_no[x]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please please please: General rule is types StartWithCapitals variables_do_not. you doing the reverse make the code hard to read.

Comment: @John3136, that's a stylistic guideline and has absolutely nothing to do with the C language per se. Identifiers (of which types and variables are two) follow the *same* rules. In fact, I often do things like `typedef struct sSomething { ... } tSomething;`, which is plenty readable :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Yep, your right. It's a style thing. We both know there is more than one workable style, but OPs style is not one that we'd expect to see as professionals which means their code is hard for others to read and maintain. I think it's a reasonable comment (not an answer) - hopefully OP will read it and learn something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not using `realloc` correctly. With regards to your code:

```
pb Book = {'\0', '\0', '\0'};
pb *PhoneBook = (pb *) calloc(5, sizeof(pb));
PhoneBook = &Book;
```

While that *second* line sets `PhoneBook` to an address in the memory arena (i.e., one that can be passed to `realloc`), the *third* line causes it to point at an item outside of the arena.

Calling `realloc` with that pointer is undefined behaviour.

I'm not *entirely* certain what your intent is there with that third line. If it's to ensure that the fields are initialised to NUL characters, `calloc` already does that.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
pb *PhoneBook = (pb *) calloc(5, sizeof(pb));
PhoneBook = &Book;
```

You allocate space for 5 pb structs, but then you discard that pointer and instead set `PhoneBook` to point to `Book`, which is on the stack.  So you aren't even using the result of `calloc` at that point, and you can't `realloc` something from the stack.

You could do something like this instead:

```
pb *PhoneBook = (pb *) calloc(5, sizeof(pb));
PhoneBook[0] = Book;
```

That will perform a structure copy of `Book` into the first element of `PhoneBook`.  But if you're going to check if `calloc` failed, you should do so before the structure copy.